# winrt adding service reference (json not asmx)

Tags: json, web, service, reference, windows-runtime

I want to add service reference but when i copy my url it says:

> "There was an error downloading metadata from the address. Please
>   verify that you have entered a valid adress."

My url isn't asmx it's json, in details:

> "... was not recognized as a known document type."

Is anyone knows how to reference json in winrt?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***My url isn't asmx it's json***

It means that you are using the WCF Rest Service(Json), if so for the WCF Rest Service we can not add the service references, we need to use the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298639)/[HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.105).ASPx) to help us consume the service in the Windows Runtime.

For more inforation about how to consume the Json service from the Winrt, please try to check this MSDN sample:

[How to use HttpClient to post Json data to WebService in Windows Store apps](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-use-HttpClient-to-b9289836)

Have a nice day. :)